# How can I select visible loose edges during cloth animation?

Tags: edges, cloth-simulation

I'm working on converting a mesh by adding cloth physics. The simulation is going OK, but when I run it, I can see there are some edges that sort of hang loosely off the rest of the mesh from cloth physics being applied. They aren't connected to any faces. But it's really hard to find them individually in edit mode because the mesh returns to its original pose with no cloth physics.

I think these loose edges are messing with the self collision on the mesh. I've been painstakingly going through clicking on edges and trying to delete the ones that aren't supposed to be there, but it's going to take a long time if I do it this way. Is there any way to tell Blender to select those loose edges while still on object mode, or to apply the cloth physics during edit mode so I can easily select and delete them?

Comment: If you activate the addon called Mesh: 3D-Print Toolbox, you can open the N panel > 3D-Print > Clean Up > Make Manifold, the floating edges will be deleted